# Estimating parameters and latent variables in a split Poisson distribution using R and JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, poisson-process

I am trying to estimate parameters and latent variables in a split Poisson model that describes observable and unobservable counts in time assuming the split probability is $\pi$. An observable event in time is denoted as $O_t$ while an unobservable event is denoted $U_t$. The distributions of $O_{t+1}$ and $U_{t+1}$ are assumed to follow the conditional distribution:

$O_{t+1}|O_{t},U_{t}$ ~  Poisson$[\pi(\mu_{t}O_{t}+\mu U_{t})]$

$U_{t+1}|O_{t},U_{t}$ ~  Poisson$[(1-\pi)(\mu_{t}O_{t}+\mu U_{t})]$

$\mu$ and $\mu_r$ are type specific rates  where $\mu_{t} = \mu$ if $t \le C$ and $\mu_t = \mu_r$ if $t \gt C$; $t=1,2,\ldots,C-1 , C, C+1, \ldots,N$.

Data is available for all $O_t$. Each latent variable $U_t$ is to be updated using the relation above and assuming that $U_{t} = 0$. It is desired to estimate parameters $\pi$, $\mu$, $\mu_r$ and the latent variables $U_{t}$ for all $t$. Bayesian method is chosen to carry out these estimations and my code is given below:

```
    library(R2jags)
    # sample observable data for 30 time points
    o <- c(1, 1, 2, 11, 15, 30, 60, 46, 60, 54, 51, 44, 27, 20, 16, 10, 7, 7, 4, 4, 6, 10, 8, 10, 2, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0)
    # setting the input for jags model function
    oo <- data.frame(o)
    datain <- as.list(oo)
    datain$n <- nrow(oo)
    datain$C <- C
    model <- function() {
        u[1] <- 0    #bringing in the data through loop and minding the rate conditions
        for (i in 2:C) {
            o[i]~dpois(pi*(mu*o[i-1]+mu*u[i-1]))
        }
        for (i in (C+1):n){
            o[i]~dpois(pi*(mur*o[i-1]+mu*u[i-1]))
        }
        pi~dunif(0,1)     # setting non-informative priors
        mu ~ dunif(0,10)
        mur ~ dunif(0,1)

        for(j in 2:C){    # the priors for the latent variable are updated via the conditional relation
            u[j]~dpois((1-pi)*(mu*o[j-1]+mu*u[j-1]))
        }
        for(j in (C+1):n){
            u[j]~dpois((1-pi)*(mur*o[j-1]+mu*u[j-1]))
        }

    }

    parameters <- c('pi','mu','mur','u[10]','u[15]','u[20]') # usually we obtain distribution for all latent variables but only decide to choose these three.
    jagsfit <- jags(datain, model=model,parameters=parameters,
            n.chains=2,n.iter=5000000,n.burnin=100000,n.thin=5000)
    jagsfit
                  mu.vect     sd.vect         2.5%          25%          50%                  75%
    u[10]    1.402007e+04    2037.291 1.103313e+04 1.213150e+04 1.397350e+04 1.561675e+04
    u[15]    1.251555e+06  130601.609 1.055833e+06 1.132489e+06 1.251471e+06 1.352963e+06
    u[20]    1.136881e+08 7039334.938 1.028741e+08 1.072936e+08 1.138424e+08 1.191725e+08
    mu       2.466000e+00       0.021 2.431000e+00 2.449000e+00 2.465000e+00 2.485000e+00
    mur      1.860000e-01       0.157 8.000000e-03 6.500000e-02 1.470000e-01 2.570000e-01
    pi       0.000000e+00       0.000 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
    deviance 1.512097e+04     143.825 1.487507e+04 1.499773e+04 1.510491e+04 1.524422e+04
                    97.5%  Rhat n.eff
    u[10]    1.771087e+04 0.998   200
    u[15]    1.488133e+06 0.997   200
    u[20]    1.262587e+08 0.998   200
    mu       2.499000e+00 0.997   200
    mur      6.220000e-01 1.004   200
    pi       0.000000e+00 1.001   200
    deviance 1.534904e+04 0.997   200
```

I simulated the observed data above by fixing parameters and writing function below:

```
    set.seed(123)
    C =7;mu=2;mur =0.4;pi=0.7
    o <- numeric(); u <- numeric()
    o[1] <- 1; u[1] <- 0
    f <- function(){
        for(i in 2:30){
            if(i <= C){
        o[i] <<- rpois(1,pi*(mu*o[i-1]+mu*u[i-1]))
        u[i] <<- rpois(1,(1-pi)*(mu*o[i-1]+mu*u[i-1]))
    }else{
        o[i] <<- rpois(1,pi*(mur*o[i-1]+mu*u[i-1]))
        u[i] <<- rpois(1,(1-pi)*(mur*o[i-1]+mu*u[i-1]))
    }
}
return(list(o,u))
}

f()
```

In this case, the unobservable is:

```
u <- c(0, 1, 3, 0, 7, 12, 31, 32, 26, 20, 22, 15, 13, 8, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

I want to recover the parameters and the latent variables back but the results I got were not OK and was thinking I have mis-specified some of the distributions. Can anyone please help look this problem? Thanks!